# Azure Data Studio does not properly import CSV

Tags: csv, flat-file, azure-data-studio

Please would you help me out with this error.

I am trying to import a csv file through the wizard, downloaded here https://ourworldindata.org/covid-deaths.

But unfortunately it is not converting all floats.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Vsk.png)

Thank you in advance!

Tried cast the data type in a script after uploading a csv all float columns as all varchars, it uploaded and then I tried to change data types in a script manually. It still gives an error that it is impossible.

Comment: Are you in a locale which uses comma(,) as decimal separator?

Comment: That's a single quote (`'`) not a comma (`,`), @RogerLindsjö .

Comment: Thank you for reply. Why should be a comma? other csv tables are imported correctly. The problem only with this one.. Thank you!

Comment: it shows the error while importing trough wizard: ✗ Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpProcessException: Error inserting data into table.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The given value '0.0' of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type float for Column 5 [new_cases].
---> System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double.
---> System.FormatException: The input string '0.0' was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, ReadOnlySpan`1 value, TypeCode type)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue in my environment. Downloaded the csv file from given link and tried to import the file into azure data studio. I got the same error:

[image]

While importing CSV files Azure data studio taking `nvarchar(1)` data type to the string columns by default. I changed the datatype to  `nvarchar(50)` to the string columns and selected `Allow Nulls` values to all columns to insert including null data.

[image]

After above changes the data imported successfully into database.

[image]

While importing the once check the data types according to the data.
Imported data table:

[image]

Comment: thank you!I tried the same in my answer below. Still the error.

Comment: As mentioned in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/V8g9TI3.png) I just changed the string columns datatype length didn't change another columns datatype. It imported successfully.  Share your sample data I will try with that.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_ud2G-NT49foL60qU60mKUbfh_C9moSP
here are 2 .csv files made up from the file, I separated for convenience. 
There are also screenshots of steps I took. Thank you @Bhavani

Comment: Check with [this](https://i.imgur.com/JT3hgya.png). It was able to import csv deaths.csv file

Comment: Some of your data is mixed with characters and digits for that type of data we need to mention them as nvarchar(50) datatype. we don't have any other option.

Comment: Do you mean that cells have floats and then suddenly have Jul.27 ?

Comment: I appreciate your help and time! Was very glad that someone replied @Bhavani